# Convert Array To Collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections

I have the following array in PHP:

```
[
  {
     "website": "example",
     "url": "example.com"
  },
  {
     "website": "example",
     "url": "example.com"
  }
]
```

Now I would like to convert this to a collection so I sort by the keys `website` or `url`.  However when I do this:

```
$myArray = collect(websites);
```

I get this instead:

```
 {
      "0": {
         "website": "example",
         "url": "example.com"
      },
      "1": {
         "website": "example",
         "url": "example.com"
      }
    }
```

And the sorting does not work, I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it so I have an array collection of objects I can easily sort.

**Edit:**
I expect the output to be the same as this:

```
[
  {
     "website": "example",
     "url": "example.com"
  },
  {
     "website": "example",
     "url": "example.com"
  }
]
```

By "sorting does not work" I meant the items are not sorted.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be

Comment: And what do you mean by "the sorting does not work"?

Comment: What I posted on top, didn't expect it to change from the original

Comment: Your question makes no sense in its current form

Comment: It didn't change, though. Your normal array has indices too.

Comment: Edited my post, and it did change because that is how it is being returned to the client which is a problem because it reads that as an object with the keys 0,1........etc. instead of an array of objects

Comment: 1) The thing is, your first array has numeric keys as well, even if they don't show in your print-out above. 2) A collection is an object, you can't have a collection and not want it to be an object. 3) Your array does not appear to contain objects either, although it's hard to tell for sure depending on how you print the results.

Comment: I know that however that is the response being returned to the client and there is a big difference between a json object and a json array.

Comment: Well, if you have a collection and you want specific output, you want to use the `->map()` method on collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map

Comment: This might help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488623/how-can-i-convert-array-two-dimensional-to-collection-laravel/54785375#54785375](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488623/how-can-i-convert-array-two-dimensional-to-collection-laravel/54785375#54785375)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Edit; I understand this question is getting a lot of hits based on the title so the TLDR for those people is to use the `collect()` helper to create a Collection instance. In answer to the questioner's brief:

If you have

```
$collection = collect([
    (object) [
        'website' => 'twitter',
        'url' => 'twitter.com'
    ],
    (object) [
        'website' => 'google',
        'url' => 'google.com'
    ]
]);
```

You then have your array wrapped in an instance of the Collection class.
That means it does not behave like a typical array (- it will be array-like, but don't treat it like it is one -) until you call `all()` or `toArray()` on it. To remove any added indices you need to use `values()`.

```
$sorted = $collection->sortBy('website');

$sorted->values()->all();
```

The expected output:

```
[
     {#769
       +"website": "google",
       +"url": "google.com",
     },
     {#762
       +"website": "twitter",
       +"url": "twitter.com",
     },
]
```

See the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods

The `toArray` method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays.

The `all` method returns the underlying array represented by the collection.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you, I understand how it works now and it worked when I tested it. :)

Comment: Short answer: Use `collect($arr)`.

Comment: Short answer extended: There are different collections. 1. collect(array $array) or 2. new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection(array $array).  First returned collection from type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection. In some cases, however, you need the Eloquent Database Collection, then you take the second one.

Answer (score 20):

In my case I was making an collection to fake a service for test purpose so I use

```
$collection = new Collection();
    foreach($items as $item){
                $collection->push((object)['prod_id' => '99',
                                           'desc'=>'xyz',
                                           'price'=>'99',
                                           'discount'=>'7.35',

                ]);

            }
```